# CSS scroll animation restarts before all text has scrolled

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a list of 100 paragraphs repeatedly scroll up, but the animation is restarting before the list finishes scrolling, at about 48 paragraphs.  How can I make sure that all paragraphs scroll before the animation restarts?

```js
div = document.getElementById("titlecontent");
for (c = 0; c < 100; c++) {
  str = c;
  p = document.createElement("p");
  p.innerText = str;
  div.appendChild(p);
}
p = document.createElement("p");
p.innerText = "last p reached";
div.appendChild(p);
```

```css
#titlecontent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: scroll 10s linear 0s infinite;
  -moz-animation: scroll 10s linear 0s infinite;
  -ms-animation: scroll 10s linear 0s infinite;
  -o-animation: scroll 10s linear 0s infinite;
  animation: scroll 10s linear 0s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scroll {
  0% { top: 100%; }
  100% { top: -170%; }
}
@-moz-keyframes scroll {
  0% { top: 100%; }
  100% { top: -170%; }
}
@-ms-keyframes scroll {
  0% { top: 100%; }
  100% { top: -170%; }
}
@-o-keyframes scroll {
  0% { top: 100%; }
  100% { top: -170%; }
}
@keyframes scroll {
  0% { top: 100%; }
  100% { top: -170%; }
}
```

```html
<div id="titlecontent"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem lies with top/bottom being related to the height of the screen, since the `div` is longer than those dimensions, it won't work.

I think I found a good solution, using only CSS.

Animating the top/bottom values is impossible, since CSS animations require their exact counterpart to animate, however, there is a property we can use to animate based on the entire height of the element

#### Introducing: CSS Transforms (translateX).

```js
div = document.getElementById("titlecontent");
for (c = 0; c < 100; c++) {
  str = c;
  p = document.createElement("p");
  p.innerText = str;
  div.appendChild(p);
}
p = document.createElement("p");
p.innerText = "last p reached";
div.appendChild(p);
```

```css
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#titlecontent {
  animation: scroll 20s linear 0s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scroll {
  0% { transform: translateY(10%); }
  100% { transform: translateY(-100%); }
}
```

```html
<div id="titlecontent"></div>
```

The magic happens in these lines:

```
  0% { transform: translateY(10%); }
  100% { transform: translateY(-100%); }
```

Instead of animating offset, we're animating the element's position on the X axis of the screen. Making it -100% of it's actual height, and then animating it to 100% of it's actual height, effectively animating it offscreen before it repeats.

You just need to decide where the scrolling up should start, in this example 10%

Comment: Thank you for downvoting, if that's not the solution, or you think it's not the *right* solution, please let's discuss the solution you're after.

Comment: Your Idea is good, you got the idea of the solution, but you didn't actually solved it

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate, could you explain me how? I'd like to poke around in that case.

Comment: I edited your solution, it is fixed now. You were scrolling from up to down very fast, not doing what it was asked